# Prove $\frac{k^7}7+\frac{k^5}5+\frac{2k^3}3-\frac k{105}$ is a integer by mathematical induction

Tags: induction

This is what I got:
If this must be possible i.e.if it must be an integer then $(\frac{15k^7}{7} + \frac{21k^3}{3}+ \frac{70k^2}{2}-k)$ must be divisible by 105.
$k(\frac{15k^6}{7} + \frac{21k^2}{3} + \frac{70k}{2}-1)$ must be divisible by 105. For the purpose of using math induction I found out htks, but then I am stuck!!
Therefore it works for 1 but how do I further prove it for $k+1$?

Comment: I assume you mean $\frac{k^7}7$ and not $k^{7/7}$, but it's hard to tell. Please, follow a guide like [this one](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) when writing mathematics on this site to make it more readable.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1916947/proof-using-the-mathematical-induction/1918565#1918565

Comment: You probably meant that $15k^7+21k^5+70k^2-k$ must be divisible by $105$, since the whole point of multiplying by $105$ is to remove the fractions..

Answer (score 2):

Observe that $\dfrac{k^7}{7}+\dfrac{k^5}{5}+\dfrac{2k^3}{3}-\dfrac{k}{105}=\dfrac{15k^7+21k^5+70k^3-k}{105}$.

So you essentially need to prove that $15k^7+21k^5+70k^3-k$ is a multiple of $105$.

---

**First, show that this is true for $k=1$:**

$15+21+70-1=105$

**Second, assume that this is true for $k$:**

$15k^7+21k^5+70k^3-k=105m$

**Third, prove that this is true for $k+1$:**

$15(k+1)^7+21(k+1)^5+70(k+1)^3-(k+1)=$

$\color\red{15k^7+21k^5+70k^3-k}+105k^6+315k^5+630k^4+735k^3+420k^2+105k=$

$\color\red{105m}+105k^6+315k^5+630k^4+735k^3+420k^2+105k=$

$105(m+k^6+3k^5+6k^4+7k^3+4k^2+k)$

---

Please note that the assumption is used only in the part marked red.

Answer (score 1):

Multiply by $105$ to get
$$
15k^7 + 21k^5 + 70k^3 -k == 105 x
$$
and the problem is solved if we can show $x$ is an integer.  That is, we wish to show the left hand side is $0 \pmod {105}$.

For $p$ prime, $k^p = k \pmod p$

Consider, then, the left hand side, in mod $3$:
$$
70k^3 - k \equiv 1 k^3 - k \equiv 0 \pmod 3
$$
Similarly,
$$
21k^5 - k \equiv 1 k^5 - k \equiv 0 \pmod 5 \\
15k^7 - k \equiv 1 k^7 - k \equiv 0 \pmod 7 \\
$$
Therefore, the LHS is $0$ in mods 3, 5, and 7, so it is zero mod 105.

Comment: An elegant solution, but the OP asked for mathematical induction.